# Function that applies a function x times on an argument

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

Write a `doItX :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> Int -> a` function that applies the first parameter `f` `x` times on the second parameter.

```
doItX (*) 2 1 == 2

doItX (++) "a" 6 == "aaaaaa"

doItX (*) 2 3 == 8
```

I have the following code:

```
doItX f a x
  | x==1 = a
  | x>1 = doItX f (f a a) (x-1)
```

That works fine if `x` is 2 or less, but for the third example, it returns `16` instead of `8`.

Comment: Did you consider this: `doItX fn v n = foldr1 fn (replicate n v)`

Comment: @jpmarinier Guessing by context a `foldr` is probably not the goal of the exercise.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann - Yes I agree, so I have written an answer with both options, the library-based one and the for-school one.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the most “*idiomatic*” solution would be a library-based one:

```
doItX1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> Int -> a
doItX1 f a x = foldr1 f (replicate x a)
```

with [Prelude function *foldr1* documented here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr1).

But if for some reason of yours, you insist on using manual recursion, your code was almost there. You just need to fix the recursive call:

```
doItX :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> Int -> a
doItX f a x
  | (x > 1)    =  ----Was: doItX f (f a a) (x-1)
                  f a (doItX f a (x-1))
  | (x == 1)   =  a
  | otherwise  =  error ("doItX called with x set to " ++ (show x))
```

Comment: IMO `iterate` would be more idiomatic than `foldr1`: `doItX f a x = iterate (f a) a !! (x - 1)`

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider `doItX (*) 2 3`.

```
doItX (*) 2 3
-- doItX f a x
-- f = (*)
-- a = 2
-- x = 3
-- doItX f (f a a) (x-1)
doItX (*) ((*) 2 2) 2
doItX (*) 4 2
doItX (*) ((*) 4 4) 1  -- ups, you wanted `2 * 4` but got `4 * 4`.
                       -- You probably should always pass 2 for a.
16
```